# Null Pointer Exception on Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a NullPointerException on my Dialog. Here's my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "test lang ito! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Dialog d = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
    d.setContentView(R.layout.popup_image);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setImageResource(resid[0]);
    d.show();
    return false;
}
```

in this line: `imageView.setImageResource(resid[0]);`

Comment: @craigy: how do I format a line of code? just like what you did? Thanks. :)

Comment: You put tick marks around it (same key as `~` for me). Check out the Markdown help page http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you want to look for the `ImageView` in the dialog layout, but you are looking in your Activity layout.

Try using

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.image);
```

instead and see if that fixes it.

Comment: it's giving me `WindowManagerBadTokenException`

Comment: Post the full stack trace from logcat

Answer (score 1):

Without resid it is hard to tell, but is resid null?  How many elements are in resid?  Is imageView null?